# Regarding Next & previous buttons in asp.net asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I have next & previous button when i click next button next question & their answers displays after i click on previous button it is displaying earlier question but not earlier selected answer. i want earlier selected answer. how its possible?
Asp.net c#

Comment: Is it a radio button or a check box

Comment: i used radiobuttonlist for answers

Comment: please , post some code to identify the idea, i think the list view will help you greatly to accomplish what u wanna, i use it many times to achieve things like that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the answers and prefill with them when the page loads.  In ASP.NET you can save your form data in a variety of ways, including:

- View State
- Session State
- Query string parameters
- Hidden form elements
- Database store

I don't know the nature of your application and what the best solution for you would be, but I'm leaning towards Session State.

Comment: i have session for selected answer but when i click to next page & again back to previous page then how i wil save that value ( as visiting that question 2nd time)

Comment: On page load (or pre render) event, you would need to write logic to determine if this user has answered this question (by checking session variable) and make sure IsPostback is false, and set the value of the input control to the value in session.